# Ionic 3 Angular DOM manipulation

Tags: angular, dom, ionic-framework, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to manipulate the DOM dynamically from my TS (JS) by using the following line of code:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ion-backdrop")
```

When outputting this to the console, it writes "`HTMLCollection []`".

My problem is that beyond this point, nothing appears to work. I've tried the following methods, and all don't work.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("ion-backdrop").[0].styles.background("#000")
document.getElementsByTagName("ion-backdrop")[0]. setAttribute("background", #000)
```

Can anyone suggest how can I dynamically change the background? FYI, I don't have access to the HTML (this is a native Ionic component).

Comment: why cant you apply styles from your scss for that specific class or element

Comment: @MaheshJadhav I need to update it dynamically as a certain variable changes in my TS(JS)

Comment: you can apply class dynamically then by using ngClass on whatever element you want to based on the condition

Comment: @MaheshJadhav I don't have access to HTML, so ngCLass is off limits. I'm trying to work with Ionic native loading component.